# I can't install or remove any software from software center?

Tags: package-management

I can't install or remove any software and the Ubuntu software center shows me this message when I install software:

```
Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. 
(org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.88'}): 
org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
```

and after I press <kbd>ok</kbd>, a second massage appears:

```
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.88'}): 
org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: that edit looks terrible edward, long horizontal scrollbars are much less readable than the  nicely wrapped original Q. And does that error even show up in a terminal? Or in a nicely wrapped pretty gui window?

Comment: @xen2050: Be nice to Edward!  Sometimes there are no perfect solutions... :P  ;-)

Comment: @edward-torvalds: please review my edits and apply the same system next time you edit a question. ;)

Comment: @edward-torvalds: My edits haven't been peer reviewed yet. Look again an an hour or two and have a look at what I changed and how I changed it.  You're doing the right thing and your edits were better then the original, but mine are slightly better. ;-) :P The goal is to improve readability for anyone opening the question.

Comment: Sorry edward, not trying to be mean! Just expressing an opinion of the edit only. If there were a better way to "downvote" an edit I'd do it, is there one? What's the best thing to do in the future?

Comment: @Xen2050: there's no way to comment on an edit besides leaving a comment on the post mentioning the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to use `synaptic` or apt (`apt-get` specifically) I don't think they use the policy kit that's having problems, in case the answers in the (older) possible-dup-Q don't work.